# Can properly written code using mutex be still volatile?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdthread

I've been doing pretty basic stuff with std::thread without any particular reason, simply in order to learn it. I thought that the simple example I created, where few threads are operating on the same data, locking each other before doing so, worked just fine, until I realized that every time I run it the returned value is different, while very close to each other, I am pretty sure they should equal each other. Some of the values I have received:

- 21.692524
- 21.699258
- 21.678871
- 21.705947
- 21.685744

Am I doing something wrong or maybe there is underlying reason for that behaviour?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <mutex>

using namespace std;

mutex mtx;
mutex mtx2;

int currentValue = 1;
double suma = 0;

int assignPart() {
    mtx.lock();
    int localValue = currentValue;
    currentValue+=10000000;
    mtx.unlock();
    return localValue;
}

void calculatePart()
{
    int value;
    double sumaLokalna = 0;
    while(currentValue<1500000000){
        value = assignPart();
        for(double i=value;i<(value+10000000);i++){
            sumaLokalna = sumaLokalna + (1/(i));
        }
        mtx2.lock();
        suma+=sumaLokalna;
        mtx2.unlock();
        sumaLokalna = 0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    clock_t startTime = clock();
    // Constructs the new thread and runs it. Does not block execution.
    thread watek(calculatePart);
    thread watek2(calculatePart);
    thread watek3(calculatePart);
    thread watek4(calculatePart);

    while(currentValue<1500000000){
        Sleep(100);
        printf("%-12d %-12lf \n",currentValue, suma);
    }
    watek.join();
    watek2.join();
    watek3.join();
    watek4.join();
    cout << double( clock() - startTime ) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC<< " seconds." << endl;
    //Makes the main thread wait for the new thread to finish execution, therefore blocks its own execution.
}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's fine.  Your output appears to be the time it takes to execute, which is unlikely to be the same every time, since you are spawning several threads that have to interact via the mutex.

Comment: The values that you show, are those values for `currentValue`? If so, should you not printf currentValue _after_ joining the threads?

Comment: Where does your output come from? The only two outputs - `printf` and `cout` do not match what you had shown. Is it something done at the end but is not pasted it?

Comment: The output I mention is the value of suma when currentValue reaches 1500000001.

Comment: By "the returned value", do you mean the final value of `suma`? Your code isn't printing that; it prints various intermediate values (which could be anything, and give undefined behaviour since you read it without locking the mutex), and the overall time taken (which will vary from run to run). Perhaps you could update the code to print exactly what you're asking about.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten is correct, when I changed the code so that it prints the value after joining the threads, it works just fine. Thank You!

Comment: `while(currentValue<1500000000)` is unprotected, in *both* cases it is used. You also don't need a mutex for this, you should be able to structure this with an `std::atomic_int`. Either that or I'm totally not seeing what this is trying to do.

Comment: WhozCraig, only thing I am trying to do is to discover the possibilities I have, I am aware that atomic_int would do just fine in this situation.

Comment: Isn't it still wrong as we are reading currentValue: `while(currentValue<1500000000)` and entering into loop (which will change value of `currentValue`) without locking `mtx`?

Comment: You should be using `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>`, **not** calling `mtx.lock()` and `mtx.unlock()`. That's how C++11 mutexes are intended to be used, not via manual locking. Use the tools provided. There is a race condition on `currentValue`, the `main` thread must lock the mutex to read `currentValue`, or you could make it a `std::atomic<int>`. `Sleep` is not portable, you can use `std::this_thread::sleep_for()` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop

```
while(currentValue<1500000000){
    Sleep(100);
    printf("%-12d %-12lf \n",currentValue, suma);
}
```

is printing intermediate results, but you're not printing the final result.

To print the final result, add the line

```
    printf("%-12d %-12lf \n",currentValue, suma);
```

*after* joining the threads.